# How to start SSH in RHEL 6.3 rescue mode

Tags: ssh, redhat-enterprise-linux, rescue

I had a server crash on me, and i'm using Rhel 6.3 rescue mode from a USB. I was able to boot into rescue mode which gives me what looks like anaconda shell:

```
[anaconda root@localhost /]#
```

when I issue alt + f1 It also gives me:

```
 bash-4.1#
```

I have a lot of the normal functionality of my usual terminal, however I cant seem to use the service start in order to get ssh working. I tried:

```
/etc/init.d/ssh start
```

but it says no file or directory found. I also tried to issue:

```
/usr/sbin/sshd
```

but none of the commands seem to work. The networking is active on it and I am trying to get the ssh up so that we can ssh into the machine and diagnose the visible drives. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure in sshd exists on your rescue pendrive?

Comment: it looks like it does, in all of the directories i've seen binaries and links to ssh sshd unless I am mistaken